# How to make a file upload progress indicator for Mechanize with Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, file, upload, progress-bar, mechanize

I have made a little Ruby console script which upload images to a popular image host using the Mechanize gem. Is there any way to code a file upload progress indicator?

Comment: Question is too unspecific. "You made a Ruby script". Ok.. Is it console script? Do you use a GUI? Maybe it is a rails app? There is no way to help you out if we don't get all the details. [Have a look here at the how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, it's a simple console script.

Comment: Have a look at [ruby-progressbar](https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar)

Comment: I see, but how can I detect the already uploaded amount of bytes of an image?